# Dump all allocated objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios

I'm looking a way to print all allocated objects when I get

`applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning`

Is there someway I can see what objects are in memory. An system-api call, A framework, anything really.

I'm aware of Clang & debugging by code-inspection but I'm looking for a way to see at run-time why I have a memory leak.

Suggestions?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Instruments Allocations tool.  You can navigate and see all live objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use instruments->leaks tool to see where you have a leak. It's quite precise and you can see where you allocated the object.

Comment: Leaks isn't useful for determining why an application is huge *unless that app also leaks*, which is often not the case.

Comment: @bbum Ryan asked: I'm aware of Clang & debugging by code-inspection but I'm looking for a way to see at run-time why I have a memory leak. Leaks is useful to see memory leaks:)

Comment: Leaks are only useful for finding leaks;  many programs -- a vasty majority of programs -- have far larger memory use problems in allocations that will never show up in Leaks.  Leaks is not accurate;  it can't be due to the details of the runtime environment and the detection algorithm used.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of a way to do this at runtime without keeping track of all the objects yourself.  If you're doing this during debugging, you can pause execution at that point and take a "heapshot" of your process using Instruments.  That will show you *everything* that's been allocated on the heap.

Comment: Not quite;  given three snapshots A, B, and C (and a baseline before), Heapshot shows you the objects that were allocated between point A and B that still exist in C.   The plain old allocations instrument is what OP needs.  What TomSwift said...